# Put textbox in uppercase in XAML for windows 8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime, uppercase

One textbox in a page.
i can not use the converter (it is not worked) and I can not use `CharacterCasing property`
How can I put in uppercase my Textbox when i write a text ?

I use Windows runtime to develop for Windows 8.1 so I do not find many help on the internet

My code for the moment :

KeyUp :

```
String str = "hello";
str = str.ToUpper();
str.Select(str.Count(), 0);
```

KeyDown :

```
bool bModify = true;
```

My XAML code :

```
<TextBox Name="Name" KeyUp="KeyUp" FontSize="20" Margin="15" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" KeyDown="KeyDown"/>
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM?  You should post some XAML so we can see what your `TextBox` and any related bindings look like.

Comment: I have modified my first post

Comment: Where is the C# code being executed? KeyUp? KeyDown? Somewhere else?

Comment: Except KeyUp and KeyDown there isn't code

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/09276ef6-556a-4fb7-9d1b-181cf84db304/windows-8-winrt-textbox-upper-case-setting?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could leave the `TextBox` as is, but when not in focus - hide it and show a `TextBlock` instead with the same text, but with something like [`Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.typography.capitals.aspx) set.

Otherwise - this might work:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="tb"
    Width="500"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    KeyDown="OnKeyDown"
    TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>
```

C#

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoTheAllCapsThing();
}

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DoTheAllCapsThing();
}

private void DoTheAllCapsThing()
{
    var start = tb.SelectionStart;
    var length = tb.SelectionLength;
    tb.Text = tb.Text.ToUpper();
    tb.Select(start, length);
}
```